# Android adding margin top for the header view is not working in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am developing an Android application with listview which contains header. Here I am adding headder top margin every time when swipe on listview. Here I am calculating swipe event based on last Y position and current Y position. I am adding margin top by using below code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams headerLp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mHeaderView.getLayoutParams();
                    if (headerLp == null) {
                    headerLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                    }
                                    headerLp.topMargin = 100;
                                    mHeaderView.setLayoutParams(headerLp);
```

I would like to add every time 100 px while swap event done successfully. For the first time it is adding successfully  but next onwards not working. I am not getting whats was the wrong here. Please let me know expected reason for not adding margin for view while doing it by problematically.

Comment: post the rest of the code please, this part only shows where you create the layout params

Comment: Here i am using custom listview and my mHeaderView is header for that custom listview

Comment: If you don't post the entire method how can we figure out the error? You are just displaying the case where the layout parameters of the view is null.